# Importing AWS Architecture Icons into Google Slides

Tags: amazon-web-services, icons, slide

Am working on Google Slides (part of google docs), and wish to use the [AWS Architecture Icon](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/icons/) set.

The page provides support for many apps including PowerPoint, but I found no information on best practice usage with Google Slides. Googling didn't find anything either.

I can download the icons and then individually add to my presentation (as needed) manually but was hoping for a "built-in palette" like solution. Can anyone with knowledge please advise on best approach & whether there is a better way to do this than manually uploading on as needed basis.

Comment: In your situation, how about putting the icon palette using a sidebar of Google Slides? In this case, when the sidebar is opened, the zip file is downloaded from "AWS Architecture Icon", and arrange those images on the sidebar. Then, users use the icons from the sidebar. I'm not sure that whether the drag and drop of the icons from the sidebar can directly be done. But the icons selected by users at the sidebar can be inserted to the current Slide. In this case, the script is required to be created. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: You can see the document about the sidebar at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars).

Answer (score 6):

Download the .pptx file from [AWS Architecture Icon](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/icons/) and import to Google Slides via File > Import Slides.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked earlier and might not be very useful for you as of now but for others who may face the same issue with Google Slides. 
Wanted to create an architecture diagram using AWS Architecture Icons with Google Slides.
I found a link where almost all AWS Architecture Icons are available.

AWS Architecture Icons (AWS Simple Icons v2.1) are publicly available at: 
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1cch96MmZxZib_-KC6RcXkM2P6L0k_32kl_NwFFvEtv4/edit

Steps that I followed to use the icons in my presentation:

1. Selected all icons to copy them from the "AWS Simple Icons v2.1"
2. Created a new Slide in my "Google Slides" (which can be removed later from the final) presentation.
3. Pasted all the icons in the new slide
4. Used these icons to create architecture diagram in other slides by copy-paste.

It worked very well for me. 
Please share, if you find a better and easier solution to use AWS Architecture Icons.